# Parse JSON in ActionScript 3 (Native JSON)

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am loading in a JSON file into Flash CC (Flash11) using the native AS3 JSON.Parse().
Everything is loading fine and I can see the data, the issue I have, is that one of the JSON titles/tags changes its name, so it is hard to reference.

To make it a bit clearer, its a weather feed and the location can change, and I don't always know what to!

```
{
"schema-version": 1,
"request-time": "2014-12-31 00:17:38",
"feed": "WEATHER",
"data": {
    "Manchester": {
        "today": {
            "obs_time": "12:16 AM",
            "temp_c": 2,
            "humidity": 93,
            "visibility": 10,
            "pressure": 1033,
            "cloud_cover": 0,
            "wind_dir": "S",
            "wind_dir_degree": 170,
            "precip_mm": 0
        }
    },
    "London": {
        "today": {
            "obs_time": "12:14 AM",
            "temp_c": 3,
            "humidity": 87,
            "visibility": 10,
            "pressure": 1036,
            "cloud_cover": 0,
            "wind_dir": "SW",
            "wind_dir_degree": 230,
            "precip_mm": 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is the "Manchester" and "London" tags in the above JSON that can change (within 'data').

I use the following AS3 code for the JSON loader and parsing...

```
public function getWeather(): void {
        json = new URLLoader();
        json.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseJSON);
        json.load(new URLRequest(unity_weather));
    }

    protected function parseJSON(e: Event): void {
        trace("JSON Weather data loaded successfully!");

        parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json.data);

        //Header info
        uWeather.Request_time = parsedJSON["request-time"];
        uWeather.Location = parsedJSON.data;

        //Now
        uWeather.Temp_now = parsedJSON.data.Manchester.today.temp_c; //not always 'Manchester'
        uWeather.Time_now = parsedJSON.data.Manchester.today.obs_time; //not always 'Manchester'
        uWeather.Humidity_now = parsedJSON.data.Manchester.today.humidity; //not always 'Manchester'
        uWeather.Visibility_now = parsedJSON.data.Manchester.today.visibility; //not always 'Manchester'

        }
```

The problem lines are ones with '`parsedJSON.data.Manchester.....`'

Is there a way to either read/find out the tag name and KNOW its Manchester, London, Dublin, Paris..etc
Or is there a way to skip the tag/name details - something like `parsedJSON.data[0].today.temp_c` and `parsedJSON.data[1].today.temp_c`- as you would with an array.

Any help greatly appreciated.

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are looking for, you can do like this :

```
function parseJSON(e:Event):void {

    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json.data);

    // trace('request-time : ' + parsedJSON['request-time']);

    for(var city_name:String in parsedJSON.data){

        // extract data without fixing the city name in the code
        var city:Object = parsedJSON.data[city_name];
        trace('city : ' + city_name);
        trace('    temp_c : ' + city.today.temp_c);
        trace('    obs_time : ' + city.today.obs_time);
        trace('    humidity : ' + city.today.humidity);
        trace('    visibility : ' + city.today.visibility);

    }
    // gives : 
    // city : London
    //     temp_c : 3
    //     obs_time : 12:14 AM
    //     humidity : 87
    //     visibility : 10
    // city : Manchester
    //     temp_c : 2
    //     obs_time : 12:16 AM
    //     humidity : 93
    //     visibility : 10

}
```

Hope that can help you.